# How to set a literal String flowScope value on-exception?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

In my Spring web flow app, one of my `action-state` transitions looks like this:

```
    <transition on-exception="com.foo.BarException" to="barView">
        <set name="flowScope.error" value="foo.bar" type="string" />
    </transition>
```

I would like to set `flowScope.error` to the literal String "foo.bar", but Spring interprets this as a reference to the `foo` object's bar attribute. How can I force Spring to take the String literally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out: the value needs needs to be enclosed in single quotes:

`<set name="flowScope.error" value="'foo.bar'" type="string" />`